# Ubuntu 12.04.2 nvidia optimus issue

Tags: 12.04, nvidia, nvidia-optimus

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04.2 on my system (Dell XPS L702x). My system has nvidia optimus and I am not able to install optimus in order to avoid loud fan and other things like very short battery life.

I ran `lspci -vmk | grep -A 8 -B 2 VGA` in order to see what drivers are used for the hardware, the result of the command is the following:

```
Device: 00:02.0
Class:  VGA compatible controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
SVendor:    Dell
SDevice:    Device 0571
Rev:    09
Driver: i915
Module: i915

--

Device: 01:00.0
Class:  VGA compatible controller
Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
Device: Device 124d
SVendor:    Dell
SDevice:    Device 0571
Rev:    a1
Driver: nvidia
Module: nvidia_current_updates
Module: nouveau
```

I have followed the instruction at [Ubuntu Help Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Bumblebee#Installation) to install optimus but when I run `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic-lts-quantal`, 
I get the following error message:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bumblebee-nvidia : Depends: nvidia-current but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

After following the instruction at [Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work) the issue seemed to be solved, but now I am continuously getting Internal error, by the error report system I was able to get the following information:
ExecutablePath
- /usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.py
Package
- xserver-xorg-video-intel (not installed)
ProblemType
- Crash
etc...

Do I have to install xserver-xorg-vido-intel ? Can you please help me? thank you!

follows the new output of lspci -vmk | grep -A 8 -B 2 VGA

Device: 00:02.0
Class:  VGA compatible controller
Vendor: Intel Corporation
Device: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
SVendor:    Dell
SDevice:    Device 0571
Rev:    09
Driver: i915
Module: i915

--

Device: 01:00.0
Class:  VGA compatible controller
Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
Device: Device 124d
Rev:    ff
ProgIf: ff

Device: 02:00.0
Class:  Multimedia controller
Vendor: Philips Semiconductors

Comment: *How* specifically did you try to resolve the unmet dependencies, such that it "lead [you] to being unable to run [your] system"? And what do you mean by that, exactly? If you can provide more information, this can be reopened; right now, you have not yet explained how and why the solutions there didn't work. As for whether or not Bumblebee works on Precise, maybe [How well do laptops with Nvidia Optimus work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work) will help.